# How can I ask a key of the keyboard show another character in HTML?

Tags: html, keyboard, space

First let me say what is half-space for those who don't know. For example compare the two following notes.

می‌آیم -  می آیم

You can compare the distance between می and آیم when normal space and half-space are used.

As Mihan Nijat mentioned in his answer, there is an HTML code for it `&#8203;`. Usually when you use some keyboards such as *standard Iranian keyboard* there are some combined keys for it such as *Shift+B*.

Now my question is this, is it possible to define a half-space by ourselves in HTML document not using these mentioned above. So defining a specific half-space with length that we want such as 1 pixel for example. And is it possible to ask HTML to compile a character with our self-defined half-space automatically?

Comment: Are you looking for half space key in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On getting an input from the keyboard, replace it with something else.
Refer to this : [filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXH2k/6/)

In the fiddle just replace `\x20` with which ever UTF spacing option you want.

```
function transformTypedChar(charStr) {
  return charStr == "a" ? "\x20" : charStr;
}
```

Code:

```js
function transformTypedChar(charStr) {
  return charStr == "a" ? "\x20" : charStr;
}

function getInputSelection(el) {
  var start = 0,
    end = 0,
    normalizedValue, range,
    textInputRange, len, endRange;

  if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
    start = el.selectionStart;
    end = el.selectionEnd;
  } else {
    range = document.selection.createRange();

    if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
      len = el.value.length;
      normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

      // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
      textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
      textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

      // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
      // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
      // in those cases
      endRange = el.createTextRange();
      endRange.collapse(false);

      if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
        start = end = len;
      } else {
        start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
        start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

        if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
          end = len;
        } else {
          end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
          end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
}

function offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, offset) {
  return offset - (el.value.slice(0, offset).split("\r\n").length - 1);
}

function setInputSelection(el, startOffset, endOffset) {
  el.focus();
  if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
    el.selectionStart = startOffset;
    el.selectionEnd = endOffset;
  } else {
    var range = el.createTextRange();
    var startCharMove = offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, startOffset);
    range.collapse(true);
    if (startOffset == endOffset) {
      range.move("character", startCharMove);
    } else {
      range.moveEnd("character", offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, endOffset));
      range.moveStart("character", startCharMove);
    }
    range.select();
  }
}

$("#foo").keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which) {
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    var transformedChar = transformTypedChar(charStr);
    if (transformedChar != charStr) {
      var sel = getInputSelection(this),
        val = this.value;
      this.value = val.slice(0, sel.start) + transformedChar + val.slice(sel.end);

      // Move the caret
      setInputSelection(this, sel.start + 1, sel.start + 1);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="foo" cols="80" rows="8">Type in here and any 'a' will be you type will show up as a ' '</textarea>
```

Spacing codes in UTF:

```
\x20 – The standard space or \s

\u00A0 – The non-breaking space[\xC2\xA0] or &nbsp;

\x0D – Carriage Return or \r

\x0A – New Line or \n

\x09 – The tab or \t
```

Spacing options in html for your reference:

```
 - non breaking space : &nbsp;
 - en space : &#8194; or &ensp;
 - em space : &#8195; or &emsp;
 - 3-per-em space : &#8196;
 - 4-per-em space : &#8197; 
 - 6-per-em space : &#8198;
 - figure space : &#8199;
 - punctuation space : &#8200;
 - thin space : &#8201; or &thinsp;
 - hair space : &#8202;
```

Comment: Are you sure `\xC2\xA0` is the non-breaking space? Because \xC2 types the capital A with a sign above it and \xA0 types a normal space when I run put \xC2\xA0 in your fildde link!

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh `\xC2\xA0` is the utf for nbsp, I am also not sure why it didn't work. For non-breaking space use : `\u00A0`, it works.
Anyway thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I tried the new one in your link now but it puts complete space :'( Both in English and Persian the result is `b b` `ب ب` while half-space makes this kind of effect `b‌b` `ب‌ب`.

Comment: Yes, `\u00A0` is a nbsp.
Is `\u303F` what you are looking for?

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh Few more: ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER `\u200C`, Hair space `\u200A`, thin space `\u2009` and narrow nbsp `\u202F`.
Kindly refer : [utf punctuation](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp)

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh `\u200B` does it.

Answer (score 1):

**ZERO WIDTH SPACE**

The ZERO WIDTH SPACE creates space between two characters but is not actually space in same width with default space. This is very handy for Arabic and Persian scripts.

> commonly abbreviated ZWSP this character is intended for invisible
>   word separation and for line break control; it has no width, but its
>   presence between two characters does not prevent increased letter
>   spacing in justification.

HTML Entity (decimal): `&#8203;`

The complete detail is available [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).

If you want to press a key and create ZERO WIDTH SPACE for you, then use JavaScript for it with logic. Example: IF A is pressed then DO [this]. Use the keycode in the logic.

You need something like following with event add listener.

```
function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      .... code here
    }
}
```

**In the above example the `13` whole number is for `enter` key.**

If you don't have rights to change the website, and you just want to type in `textarea` or `input` and allowed to use HTML. Then use `&#8203;` code and it will work for you.

**Update:**
I just checked the website and adding zero-width space with `ctrl+b` doesn't add any bold heart for me. I copied your posted text and pasted in word program. And replaced All the ♥ with space, and then copied the text and pasted on the forum using `past from word - icon`.

See this test picture:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You really can't do anything as visitor. I suggest to contact the Administrator of the forum to replace the `heart` with ZERO WIDTH SPACE.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh I just tested on the website. And `ctrl+b` just works fine and I don't see any bold heart after posting it.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh  I doubt if there is any solution you are looking for unless the site manager fix it for you. Best of luck.

Comment: It seems that website made a solution for their problem, do you understand what does `[COLOR=#222426][FONT=Consolas]​[/FONT][/COLOR]` do?